# Error installing pandas_profiling in spyder

Tags: installation, pip, spyder, pypi, pandas-profiling

Can't install pandas_profiling in spyder

Please if you can then tell how to install pandas profiling in spyder

Also using only Spyder, Spyder IDE

Tried these:

```
pip install pandas-profiling
```

```
pip install pandas_profiling==2.5.0
```

```
pip install https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip
```

Tried running setup.py from pandas_profiling_master

This comes:

```
Collecting pandas-profiling
  Using cached pandas_profiling-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (262 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=2.11.1 in c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\spyder\pkgs (from pandas-profiling) (3.1.2)
Collecting tqdm>=4.48.2
  Using cached tqdm-4.64.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe~=2.1.1 in c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\spyder\pkgs (from pandas-profiling) (2.1.1)
Collecting visions[type_image_path]==0.7.4
  Using cached visions-0.7.4-py3-none-any.whl (102 kB)
Collecting htmlmin>=0.1.12
  Using cached htmlmin-0.1.12.tar.gz (19 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [6 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kxfhoo5r\htmlmin_c9d69781ba1c4bc19ec6208da42060a8\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
      from htmlmin import __version__
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'htmlmin'
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install `ydata-profiling` which is the newest version of pandas-profiling and I didn't have any previous version of `htmlmin` installed. I was getting the same error you have.

I had to install `django-htmlmin` first, but it returned an error saying 0.11.0 version was too old for ydata-profiling, but it seemed it could call itself already, so I could install htmlmin (from git) and it worked.

After that installing ydata-profiling was as simple as always with `pip install ydata-profiling`